# NuPack Package Management

Tags: .net, dependency-management, nuget

So when planning new projects is it safe to use [NuPack](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuPackPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx) to handle dependencies?  When I say safe, will it stick around?   Or is it going to just be a hyped project that dies (i.e. Google Wave)?  Is there really a place, or need for dependency management in .NET?

If not, what is the recommended way to handle dependencies?

Comment: FYI: Due to a conflict with another "NuPack" product, it has been renamed "NuGet": http://feeds.haacked.com/~r/haacked/~3/G8vIGk7K_3I/nupack-is-now-nuget.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuPack is currently a developer preview but a) it's actively developed and maintained by both OSS developers (like myself) and core ASP.NET Microsoft employees and b) it will be folded into the core of Visual Studio. So yes, it will be around for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

If you use anything open source in .net I don't see a case not to use it.

I've seen .net OSS project developers asking to unify this in the past, I don't see how it won't take off.

ps. Personally I'm going to use it

Comment: Going to use it here, too - but I'll wait for primetime.